# Probability of having increasing even numbers, decreasing odds

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, random

I am given a set of 9 numbers from 1 to 9 and I am asked what is the probability to randomly arrange them such that the even numbers are in increasing order while the odd numbers are in decreasing order (e.g. 246897531, or 927456381).

> The first nine natural numbers, 1,2,....9 are arranged randomly. What is the probability that the resulting number, when read from left to right, is such that the even numbers are increasing order and the odd numbers in decreasing order?

I tried taking it by cases but it was a very tedious task. Then I tried going step by step by taking the possibilities of having the first even number (2) or the first odd number (9), and then the second, third, etc...

However I'm not getting the correct probability which is: 0.0003472.

Comment: The relative ordering of the evens is independent of the relative ordering of the odds. What is the probability the evens are in order? What about for the odds? By independence, you can multiply these probabilities to get the chance they both occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to arrange the even numbers in increasing order.  Similarly there is only one way to arrange the odd numbers in decreasing order.

Choose which four of the nine positions in our final number will be occupied by the even numbers.  The remaining positions will be occupied by the odd numbers.  Further, within those positions the corresponding numbers must appear in the predescribed order.

We get then a final count of $\binom{9}{4}$ different valid numbers where all even digits are in ascending order and all odd digits are in descending order.  This is out of the $9!$ different equally likely arrangements of the digits that we are choosing from.

Thus, taking the ratio, our probability is:

$$\dfrac{\binom{9}{4}}{9!} \approx 0.0003472\dots$$

Comment: That's overkill. We can consider the order of the evens and the order of the odds, independently from each other, without worrying at all about how they are interleaved. We get simply $\frac{1}{4!}\times \frac{1}{5!}$.

Comment: @TonyK it is hardly overkill.  One of the first methods of calculating probabilities taught is to use counting techniques to count the number of outcomes in the sample space, recognize that they are equally likely to occur (*otherwise, rethink and use a different sample space*), and count the number of outcomes in our favored event and take the ratio.  Using independent events to calculate often comes later.  As for the difficulty between the two approaches, I find them no more or less difficult to understand or calculate than one another.

Comment: @TonyK if your complaint was about the *interleaving* aspect and using stars-and-bars or balls-and-bins style argument, then rephrase that step as "Choose which five of the nine positions in our nine-digit number are used by the odd numbers" which should be readily accessible to any beginner student.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think choosing which five of the nine positions will be filled with odd numbers is a simpler approach than the one in your answer.  It is certainly how I would have written the answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: That's overkill too!

Comment: @TonyK The approach you suggested is also nice.